# Power BI How to access new table from a different table using new measure

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have created a new table called Calculation Method which contains two values known as average and median.
I'm creating a new measure inside a table called Alldata but when I created the new measure inside Alldata I can't access the Calculation Method.
This is the code I'm using in the New Measure
"Avg/Med WaitList = SWITCH(VALUE('Calculation Method'[Cal]),"Average", [Average Wait List],"Median",[Median Wait List])"

please help me out I'm new to PowerBI

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `VALUE` with `SELECTEDVALUE`